# Codeigniter app.baseURL production versus development

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am hoping someone has an idea here.

I always develop my web apps locally and I use (and happen to really like) CodeIgniter. I am having one issue with the `.env` file.

I need to fill out the `app.baseURL` otherwise my AJAX code doesn't work. My local development URL is always `'appname.local'` whereas production is usually `'appname.networkname.local'` (I develop in-house apps).

Is there a way I can set `app.baseURL` in such a way that it will work in both *'production'* and *'development'* without having to change it between the two servers?

Answer (score 0):

*You normally wouldn't need the solution below, since you **only** change the base URL *'once'* in both the 'development' and 'production' environments, and forget about it altogether.*

##### Solution:

1. Edit the file: [`app/Config/App.php`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/30fe0c254f29fa80a71c62692a18414d9c708cdb/app/Config/App.php#L27)

*Don't forget to replace "http://appname.networkname.local/" and "http://appname.local/" with the respective correct environment's base URLs.*

```php
    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Base Site URL
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
     * WITH a trailing slash:
     *
     *    http://example.com/
     *
     * If this is not set then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol, domain
     * and path to your installation. However, you should always configure this
     * explicitly and never rely on auto-guessing, especially in production
     * environments.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $baseURL = (ENVIRONMENT === 'production')
        ? "http://appname.networkname.local/"
        : ((ENVIRONMENT === 'development')
            ? "http://appname.local/"
            : "");
```

2. In the *'development'* and *'production'* environment, edit the file: [`.env`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/30fe0c254f29fa80a71c62692a18414d9c708cdb/env#L23) and comment out the variable declaration below:

```
# app.baseURL = ''
```

**Note:** I hope you're not committing the `.env` file using any version control system i.e [Git](https://git-scm.com/). Since this could result in sensitive credentials being exposed to the public if the project, later on, matures from just a simple in-house application.